# Unable to install w3m and w3m-img using terminal!

Tags: command-line, software-installation, w3m

```
Gauti@DESKTOP-6G981SF:~$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to resolve host DESKTOP-6G981SF
Reading package lists... Done
Gauti@DESKTOP-6G981SF:~$ sudo apt-get install w3m w3m-img
sudo: unable to resolve host DESKTOP-6G981SF
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package w3m-img is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'w3m-img' has no installation candidate
Gauti@DESKTOP-6G981SF:~$
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you take close look at your output, updating works fine. What fails is installing `w3m-img` package. I strongly recommend that you check if you have `universe` repository enabled, because `w3m-img` package belongs to that repository. See output below:

```
$ apt-cache policy w3m-img                                  
w3m-img:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5.3-26build1
  Version table:
     0.5.3-26build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```